# How To Save Entity Relations With Audit.Net?

Tags: entity-framework, audit.net

I am using [Audit.Net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md) (Audit.EntityFramework) and I want to know how can I save an entity's relation?

Here's my configuration

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
                .UseEntityFramework(x => x
                    .AuditTypeMapper(typeName => typeof(AuditLog))
                    .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, ent, auditEntity) =>
                    {
                        auditEntity.Table = ent.Table;
                        auditEntity.AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        auditEntity.Action = ent.Action;
                        auditEntity._Changes = ent.Changes;
                        auditEntity._Entries = ev.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().Entries;
                        auditEntity.Success = ev.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().Success;
                        auditEntity._ColumnValues = ent.ColumnValues;
                        auditEntity._PrimaryKey = ent.PrimaryKey;
                    }));
```

Consider the following relationship

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public string AuthorName { set; get; }

    public IList<Post> Posts { set; get; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public string Content { set; get; }

    public virtual Blog Blog { set; get; }
}
```

I want to know what is the `Blog`'s data when I remove a `Post` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Entity Framework Data Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#entity-framework-data-provider)  gives you options to create your audit tables. So you must create an `Audit` table base on your plan and save related and extra data that you need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the `Blog` is included on the `Post` instance being deleted, you should get that information on the audit event.

For example if you delete like this:

```
var post = dbContext.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Blog)
    .First(p => p.Id == 1);
dbContext.Posts.Remove(post);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And you are including the entity objects on the Audit.EF config:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
    .ForAnyContext(_ => _
        .IncludeEntityObjects()
    );
```

You should be able to get the blog information on the `AuditEntityAction` / `CustomAction`:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(x => x
        .AuditTypeMapper(typeName => typeof(AuditLog))
        .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, ent, auditEntity) =>
        {
            if (ent.Entity is Post post)
            {
                var blog = post.Blog;
            }
            // OR, if you don't IncludeEntityObjects:
            if (ent.GetEntry().Entity is Post post)
            {

            }
            //...
        }));
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It doesn't save relations to the `column changes`. can you prepare a simple console app for `Audit.EF`?

Comment: The relations to external tables will **not** be on the columns changes, unless you actually map the relation column (i.e. the `BlogId`) and that column changes. That's why I've suggested to use the EF Event `.Entity` or `.GetEntry().Entity`